# Where'd my camera app go?

Tags: ios, ipad, camera

I looked at [Camera app gone (not deactivated in restrictions)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92426/camera-app-gone-not-deactivated-in-restrictions), but it doesn't solve my problem.  A full shutdown/reboot did not help.  Camera app and Facetime both disappeared about the time I did the latest iOS update.  Restrictions are off.  If I turn restrictions on, Camera and Facetime are both greyed out.  I do have an Exchange account linked, but my sysadmin doesn't have Camera locked out (and other people here are still able to use it).

Is it because it's an iPad2?  Did Apple drop support for iPad2 cameras in the latest OS update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  I had an expired set of "AirWatch" MDM profiles on it that were blocking the camera.  Removed those and the camera came back!